# Android - ASMX Web Service Internet Data Usage

Tags: c#, android, web-services, ksoap2

As i mentioned at the title i've got a internet data usage problem.

I've got an **ASMX (C#)** Web service which returns an average **400 Byte JSON string/array**, when i use **KSOAP2** to get it in my android application it's showing **1.7 KB Data**
in **TrafficStats** class.

I checked everyting and all code parts which related to measuring data usage are true, i mean even i checked my phone operator about data usage for last 1 hour to control my codes.

How can i decrease this data usage? Thanks.

**Note: Maybe a compression or an explanation why data turns into 1.7 KB when it's only 400 Bytes can help me a lot.**

**Bounty Edit:Sorry about bounty but your answer doesn't meet the requirements of solution..**

Comment: Does asmx really support "direct" JSON without wrapping it in XML? If it's wrapped in SOAP it sounds reasonable.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but i think it doesnt. Also do you have an idea about this 400 Byte to 1.7 KB thing in android, it really sounds weird.

Comment: SOAP is an XML format with quite a bit of overhead. If you're passing the JSON data as a string inside SOAP, a _lot_ of overhead will be added by KSOAP/asmx during transfer. Also, you'll have some HTTP overhead, asmx adds some default headers that you'll most likely not be using.

Comment: hmm, so what do you suggest me to do i'm really confused.

Comment: Sorry about for voting the question to close. Reason : *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself*

Comment: Actually i can't place a piece of code here, it's meaningless in a question like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments returning a json string in a SOAP+XML brings a lot of overhead.

you can configure your asmx service using `ScriptMethod`  and `ScriptService` attributes to return directly json. That way, you can directly return your object from that method instead of returning a string.

Now your modified method will be something like this:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public MyClass GetID(string id)
{
    var myobj = new MyClass();
    //instead of serializing your object manually and returning a string
    //directly return your object. Webservice will do it for you.
    return myobj;
}
```

Also make sure the request is a `POST` , not a `GET` ([here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) is the explanation)

*PS: Enabling Http compression may help too . http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression*

Comment: as default httpcompression is open, but on the other hand i'll try to use your first suggestion please be patient, i'll let you know.